# Sync settings over proxy - Failed to Sync IDE settings

Tags: ssl, intellij-idea, proxy, ssl-certificate, jetbrains-ide

I can't sync my IntelliJ IDEA settings over a proxy.

When I tried to sync, I have an error :

[image: Sync]
[image: Error]

My logs show an exception with signature :

```
2021-09-02 10:00:15,784 [1760431]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start.updateIO === 
2021-09-02 10:00:15,784 [1760431]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === updateIO === 
2021-09-02 10:00:15,904 [1760551]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match. 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1974)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1969)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1968)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
    at com.jetbrains.cloudconfig.AbstractHttpClient.download(AbstractHttpClient.java:94)
    at com.jetbrains.cloudconfig.CloudConfigFileClient.list(CloudConfigFileClient.java:192)
    at com.intellij.idea.cloudConfig.ETagCloudConfigFileClient.list(ETagCloudConfigFileClient.java:36)
    at com.intellij.cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager.listFiles(CloudConfigManager.java:2659)
    at com.intellij.cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager.lambda$updateIO$15(CloudConfigManager.java:764)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.jetbrains.cloudconfig.AbstractHttpClient.download(AbstractHttpClient.java:92)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at com.jetbrains.b.a.L.a(L.java:496)
    at com.jetbrains.b.a.L.checkServerTrusted(L.java:483)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:390)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.jetbrains.b.a.L.a(L.java:489)
    ... 31 more
2021-09-02 10:00:15,906 [1760553]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === End.updateIO ===
```

### My settings

I use IntelliJ-IDEA 2021.2 (Ultimate Edition) over an enterprise proxy.

My enterprise proxy is defined in settings and the check connection is successful :

> [image: HTTP Proxy settings]

My enterprise self-signed certificate is accepted :

> [image: Server Certificates settings]

I can successfully display and install plugins from marketplace.

This is my first question, feel free to comment if I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proxy server substitutes the remote ssl certificate. You should either exclude the proxy for [JetBrains account](https://account.jetbrains.com) or add your custom certificate that your proxy uses into the IDE JDK [which IDE uses to run](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html). This bundled JDK is located in `<IDE HOME>/jbr` directory.

See [Import the Certificate as a Trusted Certificate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/rstep1.html) about steps how to import the certificate into the JDK.

Please note that you must be sure what you are doing when importing custom certificate. You may want to contact your IT department about this.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I had added the certificate in my personal JDK but not in that bundled one.